# npm install not responding after silly idealTree buildDeps

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npx

I'm new to react, nodejs and npm. The issue began when I tried to create a react app, so I ran the following:

```
npx create-react-app frontend
```

Nothing happened. Then, I tried:

```
npm install create-react-app
```

And the terminal is stuck in:

```
idealTree:publishbot: sill idealTree buildDeps
```

Checked the logs in `npm/_logs`:

```
0 verbose cli /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/npm
1 info using npm@9.5.1
2 info using node@v18.16.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 1ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 1ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:file:/home/safaltayanamaha/Proyectos/publishbot/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:file:/home/safaltayanamaha/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:file:/usr/local/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load Completed in 7ms
17 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 7ms
18 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 0ms
19 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
20 verbose title npm install create-react-app
21 verbose argv "install" "create-react-app" "--loglevel" "verbose"
22 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
23 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 3ms
24 timing npm:load:display Completed in 5ms
25 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:/home/safaltayanamaha/.npm/_logs/2023-04-18T16_41_27_028Z-
26 verbose logfile /home/safaltayanamaha/.npm/_logs/2023-04-18T16_41_27_028Z-debug-0.log
27 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 5ms
28 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
29 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
30 timing npm:load Completed in 21ms
31 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
32 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 1 files
33 silly logfile done cleaning log files
34 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
35 timing idealTree:init Completed in 15ms
36 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 2ms
37 silly idealTree buildDeps
38 silly fetch manifest create-react-app@*
```

**EDIT:**

Looks like the issue is general. Tried installing other packages like Babel with the same outcome:

`idealTree:lib: sill idealTree buildDeps

Not sure what else to try. Before this, I had other issues, I had to reinstall Ubuntu and upgrade everything. Please Help.

Comment: have you tried running `npm install -g create-react-app` to install create-react-app?

Comment: @LakshithaWisumperuma yes, it gets stuck in `silly idealTree buildDeps`

Comment: Might be IPv6, you can disable it and try. Apart from that you can set `npm set strict-ssl false`.

Comment: no worries. I posted it as the answer so that it might help someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably an IPv6 issue, you can disable it and try. There is issue open in [npm/cli repo.](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/3359)
Apart from that you can set `npm set strict-ssl false`